# Microsoft Word How to get the page number of selected shape / object

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with MS Word 2016 using VBA.

I need to know what page number a programmatically-selected shape (rectangle) is on. I have dozens of these rectangles that I will be accessing in a loop and they are scattered over hundreds of pages.

I just need a way to know for a given selected shape, which page it is displayed on.

Is it possible to determine that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Work with **[Selection.Information Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820800.aspx)***

> *<sub>**[Selection.Information Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820800.aspx)** 
>
>   Returns information about the specified selection. Read-only Variant.</sub>*

*Example here I'm using Debug.Print on Immediate Window*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    'Print information on selected Item.
    Debug.Print "Page: " & Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
End Sub
```